# ReactJS: How to configure browserHistory of react-router on glassfish server

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, reactjs, glassfish, react-router

I'm using a Glassfish webserver where a Java Restful webservice is running on. The client is programmed with Reactjs. I have recently implemented the react-router and found out that there is a problem with refresh of pages and direct access to react links because these requests are handeled by the server.

There is a recommendation how to solve this problem on Apache server with `.htaccess`. 
[see react-router: Histories](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md). Unfortunately this concept does not not exist on Glassfish webservers.

Anybody found a solution to this on Glassfish?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're doing - are you trying to get GlassFish to run a Javascript application?

Comment: No, only Java webservice runs on server. The routing is done in the react-router which runs in the browser. Read the attached link to get a better picture. What I'm basically looking for is a .htaccess mechanism for Glassfish server.

Comment: So you have a ReactJS frontend application serving pages which then calls a backend REST service which runs on GlassFish. Is there a reason why you can't run the frontend application on Apache? GlassFish is very different to Apache/Nginx etc and doesn't have the same kind of configuration options. It was built to solve different problems. You may be able to achieve what you want with GlassFish, but it would likely be an awkward workaround. You could also just put Apache as a proxy in front of GlassFish and have it forward requests to GlassFish.

Comment: Apache as proxy is not an option. I don't know what you mean with running the frontend on Apache? This doesn't make sense to me. Frontend will always run on client.

Comment: Switched to hashHistory on react-router. Not what I wanted but works.